# C++ Pointer Arithmetics

Tags: c++, pointers

Given the code:

```
int arr[] = {11,22,33,44,55}
for(int i = 0; i <5 ; i++)
    cout << *(arr+i) << " ";
```

Does `*(arr+i)` have the same effect as `arr[i]`?

Comment: yes, it does, it's exactly the same.

Comment: Easy to test, what happens when you replace it with `arr[i]`

Comment: It's even the same as `i[arr]`.

Comment: @ChristianRau great to know this.

Comment: @LouisTan It's nice "party knowledge", but don't ever use it in production code, it will drive anyone nuts who sees it and doesn't know it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. In fact, the subscript operator `E1[E2]` is defined as equivalent to `*((E1)+(E2))`:

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have the type “pointer to `T`” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration or integral type. The result is an lvalue of type “`T`.” The type “`T`” shall be a completely-defined object type. **The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`**.

Comment: Which leads to something strange, like: `i[arr]`.

Answer (score 1):

yes. array are decayed to `pointers`. Array name points to first element of array. So

```
 *(arr +i)
```

is equivalent to:

```
 arr[i]
```